.NetMaui SignalR System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException:
I'm developing a mobile chat app using SignalR in .NET Maui. The chat app works between two emulators and on a Windows machine. However, when I connect my own Android device to the application, I receive a System.Net.WebException: 'Connection reset' error.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.Maui.Devices;

namespace SignalRClient
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private readonly HubConnection hubConnection;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var baseUrl = "http://localhost";
            
            // Android can't connect to localhost
            if (DeviceInfo.Current.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android)
            {
                baseUrl = "http://10.0.2.2";
            }

            hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl($"{baseUrl}:5127/chatHub")
                .Build();

            hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
            {
                Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
                {
                    lblChat.Text += $"<b>{user}</b>: {message}<br/>";
                });
            });


            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Dispatcher.Dispatch(async () =>
                {
                    await hubConnection.StartAsync();
                });
            });
        }

        private async void btnSend_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await hubConnection.InvokeCoreAsync("SendMessageToAll", args: new[]
            {
                txtUsername.Text,
                txtMessage.Text
            });

            txtMessage.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>

<!--make sure, usesCleartextTraffic should be false for PROD-->```



{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:28341",
      "sslPort": 44341
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "SignalRServer": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7127;http://localhost:5127",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.Azure.SignalR"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES": "Microsoft.Azure.SignalR"
      }
    }
  }
}

Later, when I changed the port number to 127.0.0.1, it gave a System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException error. I want to be able to connect from my own Android phone and send messages. Could you help me?

is your local IIS setup to accept remote connections?  Is the SignalR client able to connect to the hub?  Are you monitoring any of the client connection events?

Connecting to the SignalR hub is not an issue, but I'm not familiar with the other things you mentioned. Can you help me with those? @Jason

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#handle-lost-connection

Is any proxy settings/vpn setting in your labtop ? Please disable it and try again.
